# ComboBox item return index

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, combobox

First of all im sorry for my English. Im a beginner programmer in C# using VS Express 2013.

This is my simple problem i think: 
I have a combobox (cboMantello) with two items inside. 
Then i have a button that uses the attributes of the selected item and add them into my character stats.
Another button removes that attributes.

To avoid Users spam the first button i disabled it and also set my combobox.enabled to false. 
At this point comes up the problem. On disabling the combobox, it returns on the first item in list, so if i select the second item and press the "equipe" buttom it adds the attributes, but then the combobox switch to the first item.So if i push the "remove" button the code remove the first item attributes.

I dont know how tell combobox to frezze on second item during the enabled = false phase.

Thanks for help, and sry again for my grammatical "horrors" !

Heres my code:

```
private void UpdateListaMantelliInventarioUI()
{
    List<Mantello> mantelli = new List<Mantello>();

    foreach (OggettoInventario oggettoInventario in _player.Inventario)
    {
        if (oggettoInventario.Dettagli is Mantello)
        {
            if (oggettoInventario.Quantità > 0)
            {
                mantelli.Add((Mantello)oggettoInventario.Dettagli);
            }
        }
    }

    if (mantelli.Count == 0)
    {
        cboMantello.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        cboMantello.DataSource = mantelli;
        cboMantello.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        cboMantello.ValueMember = "ID";

        cboMantello.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

private void btMantello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mantello mantellocorrente = (Mantello)cboMantello.SelectedItem;

    _player.DifesaMagica = (_player.DifesaMagica + mantellocorrente.AggiungeDifesaMagica);
    lblVesteDifesa.Text = "(+" + mantellocorrente.AggiungeDifesaMagica.ToString() + ")";
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(lblVesteDifesa, mantellocorrente.Nome.ToString());

    _player.Mana = (_player.Mana + mantellocorrente.AggiungeMana);
    lblVesteMana.Text = "(+" + mantellocorrente.AggiungeMana.ToString() + ")";
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(lblVesteMana, mantellocorrente.Nome.ToString());

    _player.Evasione = (_player.Evasione + mantellocorrente.AggiungeEvasione);
    lblVesteEvasione.Text = "(+" + mantellocorrente.AggiungeEvasione.ToString() + ")";
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(lblVesteEvasione, mantellocorrente.Nome.ToString());


    btMantello.Enabled = false;
    btTogliMantello.Enabled = true;
    cboMantello.Enabled = false;

    UpdatePlayerStats();
    UpdateListaMantelliInventarioUI();
}

private void btTogliMantello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mantello mantellocorrente = (Mantello)cboMantello.SelectedItem;
    if (btMantello.Enabled == false)
    {
        btTogliMantello.Enabled = true;
        _player.DifesaMagica = (_player.DifesaMagica - mantellocorrente.AggiungeDifesaMagica);

        lblVesteDifesa.Text = "";
        _player.Mana = (_player.Mana - mantellocorrente.AggiungeMana);

        lblVesteMana.Text = "";
        _player.Evasione = (_player.Evasione - mantellocorrente.AggiungeEvasione);

        lblVesteEvasione.Text = "";

        UpdatePlayerStats();

        btMantello.Enabled = true;
        cboMantello.Enabled = true;
    }

    btTogliMantello.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I know...dunno why it is happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the Combo Box is resetting is because you are changing its contents when you call `UpdateListaMantelliInventarioUI()` in the click event for `bntMantello`, specifically the lines `cboMantello.DataSource = mantelli;` and `cboMantello.SelectedIndex = 0;`.

Some options to consider:

- Is it necessary to update the combo box after they click equip/unequip?
- If it is, you could either add/remove from `cboMantello.Items` directly.
- You could also get the `SelectedIndex`/`Item` from `cboMantello` before you update it. After you update `cboMantello`, you could loop through the items and update the `SelectedIndex`/`Item`.

Some code:

```
private void UpdateListaMantelliInventarioUI()  
{  
    var previousSelection = cboMantello.SelectedItem;  

    ...

    else
    {
        ...

        if (cboMantello.Items.Contains(previousSelection))
            cboMantello.SelectedItem = previousSelection;
        else
            cboMantello.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn you're right thx. It is not necessary update again the list. Now i removed that and things works perfectly. Thanks again! SOLVED!

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri Glad I could help! By the way, could you check this answer as "Accepted"? :D